# How to convert regular expression to CFG?

Tags: computability, context-free

How can I convert the regular expression (ab*)*b to a context-free grammar?

When I look for examples I keep seeing plus signs in the expression but I don’t have any. Is that just a different way of writing it?

Comment: $r^+$ is just a shorthand for $r^*r$.

Comment: For the general regular expression to contextfree grammar, see this answer [Regular Expression to Context-Free Grammar](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/62539/4287)

Answer (score 3):

There is a simple algorithm to convert regular expressions to context-free grammars. It goes as follows.

Base cases:

- $\emptyset$ corresponds to the empty grammar.
- $\epsilon$ corresponds to the grammar $S \to \epsilon$.
- $\sigma$ (where $\sigma \in \Sigma$) corresponds to the grammar $S \to \sigma$.

Inductive cases:

- $r = r_1 + r_2$. Given CFGs for $r_1,r_2$ with disjoint nonterminals and starting symbols $S_1,S_2$, add rules $S \to S_1 \mid S_2$ and make $S$ the new starting symbols.
- $r = r_1r_2$. Same, adding the rule $S \to S_1 S_2$ instead.
- $r = r_1{}^*$. Same, adding the rules $S \to S S_1 \mid \epsilon$ instead.